# Can't install Ubuntu for several reasons

Tags: installation, laptop, uefi, samsung, bios

I'm having some issues installing Ubuntu on my Samsung NP-RV520-S02SE Laptop.

First off, I'm getting `error: failure reading sector somethingsomething` when booting the CD and hitting "Install Ubuntu".

I think it might be because of UEFI, but here's the second issue I'm having.

Since a couple of ways back, I've been unable to enter BIOS. So I can't check if UEFI is enabled or disabled. When booting it says "[F2] Enter BIOS" and when I hit <kbd>F2</kbd> that text changes to "Please wait.." so I'm pretty sure it's registering my command and that key <kbd>F2</kbd> key is working, yet it's just skipping the BIOS and bringing me to the Windows boot manager, or the Ubuntu CD if that's in the CD drive.

Anyone who'd know what might be wrong?

I should also mention that I'm not the best at Ubuntu, I'm fairly new.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should ***not*** install Ubuntu on a Samsung laptop in EFI mode! The reason is that there's a very serious firmware bug on at least some Samsung models that can cause the computer to be bricked.There's an Ubuntu bug report here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1040557

Matthew Garrett has further information on why it shouldn't be considered fixed, although a workaround is present in the very latest Linux kernels:

http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/22855.html

IMHO, the only safe way to use a recent Samsung computer at the moment is in BIOS mode. Unfortunately, this means re-installing Windows, or at least converting the installation to boot in BIOS mode rather than in EFI mode. (I hear that's possible, but I don't have a URL describing precisely how to do it.)

As to your problem getting into the firmware, I'm not sure. It could be another symptom of a buggy firmware. There's a tool in Windows 8 that interfaces with the firmware, so you could try using that to do your firmware fiddling, or perhaps it will at least have an option to let you get in via a more conventional route. You might also check with Samsung to see if they've got a firmware update; that might conceivably fix the problem.

Personally, though, if the computer is still within the store's return period, I'd return it for a refund and get something else. A computer that's easily bricked by software is too much of a risk; an accident the day after it goes out of warranty could cost you a lot of money!

Comment: I fixed my BIOS issue by updating the firmware and my UEFI was already disabled, however I was success full to install Ubuntu after changing the boot order. Thanks. =)